# QSqlDatbase is closed before the query finishes

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement a database object for my application, but it became a nightmare when I started using multiple connections. Below, you can see my `database` C++ class code:

```
// here are the declarations
QString server_addr;
QString username;
QString password;
QString database_name;
QSqlDatabase connection;
QString error;
QString connectionName;
QSqlQuery m_query;

// and here are the definitions
database::database(QString connectionName) {
    preferences p; p.read();

    QString iConnectionName = (connectionName == "") ? default_connection_name : connectionName;
    this->connectionName = iConnectionName;

    if (QSqlDatabase::contains(iConnectionName))
        this->connection = QSqlDatabase::database(iConnectionName);
    else this->connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", iConnectionName);

    this->connection.setHostName(p.database->server_addr);
    this->connection.setUserName(p.database->username);
    this->connection.setPassword(p.database->password);
    this->connection.setDatabaseName(p.database->database_name);
    this->connection.setPort(p.database->serverPort);

    if (!connection.open())
    {
        this->error = this->connection.lastError().text();
    }
    else this->error = "";
}
QSqlQuery database::query(QString query_text) {
    this->m_query = QSqlQuery(query_text, this->connection);
    this->m_query.exec();

    return m_query;
}
database::~database() {
    if (!this->m_query.isActive()) QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(this->connectionName);
    qDebug() << "database object destroyed\n";
}
```

The problem occurs in a another class (that uses the `database`):

```
databaseAdaptor::databaseAdaptor() {
    this->db = database();
    // other construction operations    
}
void databaseAdaptor::fetch() {
    QSqlQuery q = db.query("SELECT * FROM `activities`");
    qDebug() << "Rows count: " << q.numRowsAffected();
}
```

It worked some versions in the past, but for some reason, now the output from `qDebug()` is

```
Rows count: -1 // and it should be 2 for my current version of database.
```

In the **[Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSqlDatabase.html)**, it is said that this class' members are *thread-safe*. Could this be the problem? I mean, could the thread end before the queries finish their execution?

**If so, how can I keep the connection open until all the queries finished their execution?**

<sub>(I know it's much to read, but I am sure that other might have this problem at some point, so please take your time and read it). Thank you!</sub>

Comment: I've had a problem with running MySQL with Qt - it's not supported straight out of box. For testing purposes, I'd suggest changing QMYSQL to QSQLITE and see if that works. If yes, you know the issue is related to MySQL driver or db. If not, the problem may be with your implementation. 

Can you change contents of your MySQL db otherwise? (e.g. cmd line, direct connection or some web app)

Comment: the database shouldn't have any trouble, because it;s created with the MySQL Workbench, on localhost:3500

Comment: the line in databaseAdapter ctor:  this->db = database(); - this is redundant (most likely), since you can assign it directly, I assume this->db is a regular variable, and is by default set to "database()" (in others words: default ctor is called). Maybe the default ctor (called twice) doesn't properly connect to the db? Also, do you check if open succeeded (actually check the error message)?

Comment: Have you read my definition for the `database` constructor? it sets an `error` variable to the last error of the database. I am using `qDebug() << this->error;` for every construction, but there seems to be no error. I get, something else though in the Debug output: `QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'WORKING_DATABASE' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.`